# Cant connect to local host after successfully able to run django project in pycharm

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

I am able to Run "manage.py" in My Django Project and it successfully runs too. But I am unable to connect to local host in my browser. What could have gone wrong , Please explain?

Comment: The duplicate code repo runs successfully in  the same local machine and connects to local host too

Comment: you can share the screenshot of how the runserver is working in your pycharm, the command you used and the screenshot of your browser where it isn't working, also the url, screenshot of browser which is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port number is available or not. If not change the port number and try running again.